# how to write a code to run same function on load and on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The code is very simple, it changes a text on a blog but this blog has pagination that brings content through ajax.

So the code is changing the text on load and on ajax new content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.author').each(function(){
        $(this).text('Jim')
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('.author').each(function(){
            $(this).text('Jim')
        });
    });
});
```

The question I'm asking is can I write a better code. This doesn't look right to me because I'm executing the same code twice.

Is there a better way?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Create a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to wrapping the code in a function is to attach multiple event listeners to the `document` with the same callback, for example:

```
$( document ).on( 'ready ajaxStop', function() {
    $( '.author' ).each( function() {
        $( this ).text( 'Jim' );
    } );
} );
```

This code should run on both the `ready` and `ajaxStop` events.

**Edit**

From a quick look at the documentation this is no longer supported...

> There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, *deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0*. Note that if the DOM becomes ready before this event is attached, the handler *will not be executed*.

A "hacky" fix to this would be to do something like:

```
$( document ).on( 'ready ajaxStop', function() {
    $( '.author' ).each( function() {
        $( this ).text( 'Jim' );
    } );
} ).trigger( 'ready' );
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/j6dwu4zL/

Answer (score 2):

You could put the changing of author into a function and call that where needed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   changeAuthor('Jim');

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        changeAuthor('Jim');
    });
});

function changeAuthor(name) {
   $('.author').text(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap code with some function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Jim()
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        Jim()
    });
});

function Jim(){
      $('.author').each(function(){
        $(this).text('Jim')
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a separate function so the code is only done twice. It also might be better to call that function in the `success` method of the Ajax call so you can control for errors, instead of setting it to whatever comes back.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Author();
});

$.ajax({
    //params
    success: function() {
        Author();
    }
    error: function(response.responsetext) {
        console.log(response.responsetext);
    }
});

function Author() {
    $('.author').each(function(){
        $(this).text('Jim');
    });
}
```